# how to get the content of a JTextPane with its styled format

Tags: java, file, jtextpane

I am trying to make a simple word processor that edits the text to make it bold, italic, underline, background color and foreground color. The problem is I want to set the contents/text of the JTextPane with all its edited attributes to a **single object** to save it to another class as a data field which have other data fields like date created and the name of the document given by the user.

Comment: `getText()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#getText--

Comment: but that only returns a string not the styling done on it

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach its using html as content type for the Text Pane and string builders.

for example,

```
TextPane tp = new JTextPane();
tp.setContentType("text/html");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<span style=\"color:red\">"  + Hello red  + "</span>");
sb.append("<span style=\"color:blue\">" + Hello blue + "</span>");
...
tp.setText(sb); // will print text with the style
```

works the same in the other way,

```
String txt = tp.getText();
System.print(txt); //wil show html code
```

You can reference http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JTextPane/Style_JTextPane_with_HTML_and_CSS.htm

Comment: i think if am not mistaken the example you gave me works if i input text to the textPane but the intention is for the user to input text on the textPane through the user interface

Comment: or maybe if there is a way i can receive the content with its styling in an html format but turned into string so that i can use setText() method later that would be perfect